# Many-to-many relationship is creating a new instance which i don't want to

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities, Orders and Products, the relationship between the two is many to many, I have set the relationship but when I try to create a new order with an existing set of products its creating new products with new Ids instead of just joining them to the Orders_Product.
I have provided a screenshot of my test at the end.
here is my Orders' entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Orders")
public class Orders implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="idorder")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "orders_sequence")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "orders_sequence")
private Long idOrder;


@Column(name="idclient")
private Long idClient;

@Column(name="idmanager")
private String idManager;


@Column(name="iddeliveryman")
private String idDeliveryMan;


@Column(name="dateorders")
@JsonFormat(pattern="mm-dd-yyyy")
private Date dateOrder;


@Column(name="totalprice")
private double totalPrice;

@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL } , fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
    name = "orders_products", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idorder") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idproduct") }
)
private List<Products> products_orders ;

//getters and setters
```

My Products Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Products")
public class Products implements Serializable{

@Id
@Column(name="idproduct")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "products_sequence")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "products_sequence")
private Long idProduct;

@Column(name="labelproduct")
private String label;

@Column(name="priceproduct")
private int priceProduct;

@Column(name="descriptionproduct")
private String descriptionProduct;



@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products" )
private List<Menu> menus;


@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products_orders" )
private List<Orders> orders;

//getters and setters
```

My Orders Controller:

```
@RestController
public class OrdersController {

@Autowired
private OrdersRepository ordersRepository;

@Autowired
private ManagersRepository managersRepository;

@Autowired
private DeliveryManRepository deliverymanRepo;

@Autowired
private ClientsRepository clientsRepository;

@Autowired 
private ProductsRepository productsRepos;



@PostMapping("orders/create/{idManager}/{idDeliveryMan}/{idClient}")
public ResponseEntity<?> createOrder(@Valid @RequestBody Orders order ,@PathVariable String idManager 
        ,@PathVariable Long idClient, @PathVariable String idDeliveryMan){
    
    Managers manager= managersRepository.findByEmail(idManager);
    Clients client=clientsRepository.findByPhone(idClient);
    DeliveryMen deliveryMan = deliverymanRepo.findByEmail(idDeliveryMan);
    
    
    double price =0;
    for (Products p: order.getProducts_orders()) {
        price = price + p.getPriceProduct();
    }
    
    order.setIdClient(client.getPhone());
    order.setIdDeliveryMan(deliveryMan.getEmail());
    order.setIdManager(manager.getEmail());     
    order.setTotalPrice(price);     
    Orders newOrder = ordersRepository.save(order);
    
    return new ResponseEntity<Orders>(newOrder,HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
}
```

[Test in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYw4P.png)

Answer (score 0):

You relationship is not correct, you have created the Orders `@ManyToMany` relationship with `Products` which is correct theoretically but you need `@OneToMany` relationship with `Order` and `Order_Products`.

Remember the order has its lines, they are not product truly but should be represented by a different entity.

Products are kind of master data which you set once and use to suggest user your menu. You should have reference of this in your order lines but linking directly to `Order` will create issues like you are having.

Products should be created separately and not with order placed in system.

So, you must have an entity in between, which could be as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table("order_products")
class OrderProduct {
   @Id
   Long id; //Keep the id as per your requirement or type in db
   
   @ManyToOne(fetch=LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "order_id"
   private Order order;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"
   private Product product;
   
// getters and setter omitted
}

@Table(name = "orders")
class Order {
   
  @OneToMany(
     mappedBy = "order",
     cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}
     orphanRemoval = true
  )
  private Set<OrderProduct> orderProducts = new HashSet<>();
  
  // Other fields as you have already

  // Also add a method to add OrderProduct object to maintain this bidirectional mapping

  public void addOrderProduct(OrderProduct product) {
      orderProducts.add(product);
      product.setOrder(this);
  }
}
```

I think this is what you needed, please read in more details from [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: I already have the entity, Spring is handling it by itself, i got to fix it without changing the type of mapping and by using only the type of mapping i used, but its taking only the first product when trying to submit an order with multiple products

Answer (score 0):

In `createOrder` you receive an incoming object of type `Orders` that originates in the REST request you did. If you want this new order to refer to existing products and not new products you have to of course load the existing products from the database instead of letting Hibernate cascade the persisting of the (unmanaged) `Orders` object to its list of (unmanaged) `Products` objects.

Similar to

```
List<Products> products = new ArrayList<>();

for (Products p: order.getProducts_orders()) {
    products.add(productsRepos.findById(p.getId()));
    price = price + p.getPriceProduct();
}

order.setProducts(products);
```

Edit: This would have been obvious immediately if you hadn't set the `@ManyToMany` relationship to `cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }` by default because if you would save an `Orders` referring to a list of unmanaged `Products` you would get an exception from Hibernate.

Comment: It is working.But its taking only when product when submitting a lot of products !